# What's a safe minimum disk size for a production Kubernetes node?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I was playing around with Kubernetes on AWS with t2.medium EC2 instances having 20GB of disk space and one of the nodes ran out of disk space after a few days. It seems to be caused by a combination of Docker images and logs.

From what I've read, Kubernetes has its own Docker GC to manage Docker's disk usage, and log rotation. I'm guessing 20GB is not enough for Kubernetes to self-manage disk usage. What's a safe disk size for a production environment?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When following the standard installation with the GKE as described in the [quickstart guide](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/quickstart) you'll end up with 3 x n1-standard-1 nodes (see [machine types](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#standard_machine_types)) with 100 GB of storage per node.

Looking at the nodes right after the cluster creation then gives you these numbers for the diskspace:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root       1.2G  455M  767M  38% /
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmp             1.9G   24K  1.9G   1% /tmp
run             1.9G  684K  1.9G   1% /run
shmfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1        95G  2.4G   92G   3% /var
/dev/sda8        12M   28K   12M   1% /usr/share/oem
media           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /media
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           256K     0  256K   0% /mnt/disks
tmpfs           1.0M  120K  904K  12% /var/lib/cloud
overlayfs       1.0M  124K  900K  13% /etc
```

These numbers might give you a starting point, but as others have pointed out already, the rest depends on your specific requirements.

Comment: Thanks for digging out this info from GKE! I guess I'll try to provision 100GB for my nodes as well, and keep a close eye on the usage...

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no general answer. You have already answered yourself- you need enough space for docker images, containers and logs. How much- it depends on number of images used, containers running, amount of logs generated and amount of logs you want to keep.

Kubernetes-based applications should not create log files on pod volume. Logs should go either to shared volume (external to pod) or to log management database like elasticSearch, graylog. Pods will be created and deleted many times during cluster lifetime. Log files mounted on pod volume will disappear when pod is gone. Most likely, you want your log to live longer than that.

From experiment you already did you should know those numbers, and be able to estimate usage for your needs.

See  https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/garbage-collection/ for more details.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I was hoping that there is a "typical" configuration for this. (I wonder how much volume is allocated on GKE...)

Looking at the docs, Kubernetes does not recommend using external GC tools, are there other reasons to use docker system pune? (https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/garbage-collection/)

Comment: Indeed, you should use kubernetes garbage collection, no need to use docker prune. It does exactly same think, but garbage collection is cluster configuration - much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

I find that i can 'get by' with 5G if i really need to do so, i.e. for testing K8s scalability and so on.  Anecdotally, on two different platforms, Ive generally seen:

- At rest, I've found that nodes use 2% to 10% of my disk space on 40 node clusters, in general, when running cluster api implementations on Vsphere.  This amounts to 1-5G.
- On AWS, I've found (for example, using EKctl or cluster-api-provider-aws), that clusters can use aroud the same amoutn, roughly 2G or so, averaging around the same which I generally see in VSphere clusters

  [ec2-user@ip-192-168-76-4 ~]$ df -h
  Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/nvme0n1p1   80G  2.4G   78G   3% /

This is highly variable wrt containers that you are running, number of different images, and so on, but in general, the Kubelet itself rotates logs and doesnt end up needing a large amount of disk space over time.  If you look here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/59898, you can seee the logic around the initial implementation of max log sizes/roatation.  there are various options you can send the Kubelet itself to make this log rotation more stringent if you really need to save disk space.

In general, thus, you can expect that after running a cluster for a few weeks you'll be able to stick with whatever the steady state size is.

Make sure to check with your CRI configuration about wether images are recycled, in case you use lots of new images from time to time.